# Couldn't change the text between a Html element using JQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I have the **JQuery** code below. I changed the text between a **button** element from **+** to **x** in second **if** statement. Now, when the button is displaying **x**, I wanted to change the text to **+** in first **if** statement using `$(this).text("+");`, yet the button is displaying **x** even after the change. I have checked if the text was changed to **+** using **console.log()** and it says it has changed to **+**. But, why isn't the result showing its effect on the button?

```js
let players = [];
let remainingPlayers = 11;

$(".card > button").click(function(e) {
  let removePlayer = "";
  let index = -1;

  if ($(this).text() !== "+") {
    removePlayer = $(this).attr("value");
    index = players.indexOf(removePlayer);
    if (index != -1) {
      $(this).text("+");
      players.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(players);
      console.log($(this).text());
    }
  }

  if (remainingPlayers != 0) {
    remainingPlayers -= 1;
    players.push($(this).attr("value"));
    $(this).text("x");
    $(this).addClass("btn btn-danger button-select-players");
    $("#pl-remain").text(remainingPlayers);
  } else {
    alert("You can't select more players");
    console.log(players);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
  <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <button class="btn btn-success button-select-players" type="button" name="button" value="xyz">+</button>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="first-li list-group-item">Name</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">0</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a complete snippet please?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better understanding about how to add a [*minimal*, *reproducible* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please complete as a [mcve]

Comment: because it goes into the next if statement and changes it to x.....